# ROR: Image not getting rendered in wicked_pdf's pdf

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wkhtmltopdf, wicked-pdf

Here I am not talking about the images with wicked_pdf_image_tag. Those are working well. But when I download the pdf then it isn't rendering the image.

It is rendering like a small box.
[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gehWM.png)

**File.html.haml**

```
%img{src: "/assets/#{CONFIG[$skey]['main_logo_path']}"}
```

**File.pdf.erb**

```
<%= wicked_pdf_image_tag(CONFIG[$skey]['main_logo_path'],alt: "Logo", class: "mt-md mb-md")  %>
```

Gems used:

```
wicked_pdf (2.1.0)
wkhtmltopdf-binary (0.12.6.5)
```

Please help!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If someone is still searching for the solution of this issue. Here is the answer:

```
<%= image_tag wicked_pdf_asset_base64("logo.png") %>
```

Use image_tag wicked_pdf_asset_base64 for the images that are present in assest/images folder.

Comment: it worked for me when attaching pdf in an email. Generally I was using wicked_pdf_image_tag asset_url('logo.png') when viewing in a browser or downloading pdf but it was not working in an email attachment.

Comment: Thank you very much @User, I've been looking for a while how to show an image and this solution is the definitive one :D

Answer (score 1):

I'm looking at `wicked_pdf_image_tag` https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf/blob/2.1.0/lib/wicked_pdf/wicked_pdf_helper.rb#L21 implementation, and it tries to pick image at `/public/images/img`, but your image is at `/assets`

try `image_tag "file:///#{WickedPdf::WickedPdfHelper.root_path.join('assets', CONFIG[$skey]['main_logo_path'])}", alt: "Logo", class: "mt-md mb-md")` instead

Comment: Now it is showing me the error ```uninitialized constant ActionView::CompiledTemplates::WickedPdfHelper```

Comment: I updated, need to use qualified name `WickedPdf ::WickedPdfHelper`

Comment: It is giving me the error ```uninitialized constant WickedPdfHelper```. Is there anything that I am missing out?

Comment: If you've copied as is, there was unintentional space before `::`, I updated it

Comment: I have tried without giving space too. But the image is still not showing.